# how can I transfer health data from iPhone 5s to my new iPhone 6 plus?

Tags: iphone, ios

I got iPhone 6 plus and now want to transfer the health data from my old iPhone 5s to iPhone 6 Plus, but I don't know how. I've backed up the old one with iTunes and restore my iPhone 6 with the iPhone 5s backup file, but I can't see the heath data on iPhone 6 plus. Help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to back up your Health data using iTunes, you need to encrypt your backup by selecting "Encrypt iPhone backup" in the Summary tab in iTunes. If you don't select this option, your Health data won't back up.